# Why does my .csv file not contain any data?

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, export-to-csv, file-handling

Generally: the program should write the data read with SHT21_Read() (temperature sensor) into a csv-file. A raspberry pi model 2 with rasbian is used.

This is the c code:

```
int main(){

  unsigned long Counter;
  signed short Temperature;
  unsigned char Humidity;
  File *fp;

  Counter = 0;
  I2C_Open("/dev/i2c-1");  // Hardware Revision 2.0
  fp= fopen("sht21-data.csv", "w+");
  I2C_Setup(I2C_SLAVE, 0x40);

  while(1)
  {
    SHT21_Read(&Temperature,&Humidity);
    printf("%lu\t%.1f\t%u\n",Counter++,((float)Temperature)/10,Humidity);  //console output -> works 
    fprintf(fp, "%lu,%.1f,%u\n",Counter,((float)Temperature)/10,Humidity);
    system("sleep 1");
  }
  fclose(fp);
  I2C_Close();
  return(0);
}
```

The program creates the file, but it doesn't contain any data. Is it possible that there are any problems with the user/file permissions?

Comment: `Humidity` is an `unsigned char` that gets promoted to an `int`, but your `%u` format specifier expects an `unsigned int` => undefined behavior.

Comment: `return` is not a function. Do you write `int (x);` ir `int x;`?

Comment: And by the way, how are you breaking out of the infinite loop? `Ctrl+C`? In that case, `fclose()` will never run and the file contents may not be flushed to disk.

Comment: You really want to consider replacing `system("sleep 1");` by `sleep(1);` (which comes with `#include <unistd.h>`).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi you are right! we stop the infinte loop with CTRL+C...so what can i do to run fclose()?

Comment: @republic, you could handle the `SIGINT` signal. Or, maybe better, do not use an infinite loop in the first place.

Comment: As *workaround* you might want to put at `flush(fp);` after the `fprintf(...);`.